# Stata's margins and R's marginal effects' comparisons

Tags: r, interaction, stata, marginal-effect

I was looking for an equivalent for Stata's command lincom in R. I tried the `comparisons()` function from marginaleffects package. However, I get different confidence interval than the one from lincom in stata

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)
library(haven)

faculty <- read_dta("https://www.stata-press.com/data/mlmus4/faculty.dta")
faculty2 <- faculty |>
  mutate(marketc = market - mean(market))

lm(salary~ marketc + male *yearsdg, data =faculty2) |> 
  comparisons(
    variables = list(male = c(0,1)),
    newdata = datagrid(yearsdg = 10))
#>   rowid     type term contrast comparison std.error statistic    p.value
#> 1     1 response male    1 - 0   1678.223  792.9094  2.116538 0.03429907
#>   conf.low conf.high predicted predicted_hi predicted_lo   salary       marketc
#> 1 124.1491  3232.297  45665.84     46083.76     44405.54 50863.87 -1.379489e-17
#>        male yearsdg   eps
#> 1 0.7509728      10 1e-04
```

In STATA, the confidence interval is 124.449, 3236.001

This is coming from an example from Hsketh and Skrondal Multilevel and Longtudinal Modeling Using Stata, Fourth Edition, section 1.8

My question is why they differ in 95% CI while other estimates are identical

Comment: Can you add the Stata code?

Comment: In Stata, they used: `margins r.male at(yearsdg=10) contrast(nowald effects)`

Comment: Where does lincom come into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that this is a combination of factors.

#### `at()` vs. `datagrid()` vs. `datagridcf()`

In `Stata`, the `at()` syntax duplicates the whole dataset for each
value supplied in parentheses, computes contrasts for every rows, and
then takes the average estimate. In `marginaleffects()`, calling
`datagrid(yearsdg = 10)` sets `yearsd` to 10 and every other regressor
to their means. So we only compute a contrast for one row of data. We
can mimic the Stata process by using `datagridcf()` instead of
`datagrid()` (where “cf” stands for “counterfactual”). See here for a
detailed comparison of `Stata` and `marginaleffects`:
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#stata

#### Average contrasts

As noted above, the `datagridcf()` will produce one estimate of the
contrast per row of the dataset. `Stata`’s `margins` command computes
those unit-level estimates, but then takes their average. To do this in
`marginaleffects`, we can use the `tidy()` or `summary()` functions, or
the `by` argument.

#### Degrees of freedom

By default, `marginaleffects` uses the normal distribution to build set
critical values for the confidence intervals. Using the very latest
development version from Github, you can now set a `df` argument. I
can’t recommend this experimental argument now because its behavior
might change before the next release, but I use it here because it helps
us bring our results closer to `Stata`.

#### Transcription?

Are you sure that you transcribed those confidence intervals correctly in the question? It looks like `marginaleffects` produces very similar digits, but the lower bound is off by 10x.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)
library(haven)

faculty <- read_dta("https://www.stata-press.com/data/mlmus4/faculty.dta")
faculty2 <- faculty |>
  mutate(marketc = market - mean(market))

mod <- lm(salary ~ marketc + male * yearsdg, data = faculty2)
comparisons(
  mod,
  variables = "male",
  df = insight::get_df(mod),
  newdata = datagridcf(yearsdg = 10)) |>
  summary()
```

```
  Term Contrast Effect Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %
1 male    1 - 0   1678      792.9   2.117 0.034299 124.1   3232

Model type:  lm 
Prediction type:  response
```

Comment: Welcome to CV Vincent :) Your presence will be a boon to the community. This is completely explainable by the df issue. Stata uses a t-distribution after a linear model while `marginaleffects` uses a z-distribution. Using a high df in Stata replicates the `marginaleffects` values exactly.

Comment: May I ask which numeric version is better/more sound/more correct?

Comment: If there are still numerical differences after accounting for the different treatment of degrees of freedoms, they are only likely to appear in the standard error at the 4th, 5th, or 6th significant digit. As such, they will very rarely matter substantively. If there are remaining numerical differences, my guess is that they may arise because of different My guess is that such numerical differences arise from the choice of step size in the finite difference numerical differentiation, and I'm not aware of a good reason to prefer either the `Stata` or `marginaleffects` defaults in that respect.